# Sufficient condition for absolute convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

I want to prove the following statement

> If $\sum_{n\in I} a_n$ converges with any rearrangements of a countable index set $I$, then $\sum_{n\in I} a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

The finite case is trivial. The $\mathbb{N}$ case can be proved by contradiction invoking Riemann series theorem.

I am looking for a direct proof (hence not using contradiction).

Comment: How about contraposition?

Comment: @DavidMitra I also worked that out, but am still interested in a direct proof.